# Watch for bridge-related events using ARI

Tags: javascript, node.js, asterisk

I am trying to use Asterisk ARI to watch for bridge-related events. I am using Asterisk 13.6.0.

Specifically, I want to know when a bridge has been created or destroyed, and when a user (channel) has joined or left the bridge. On my server, bridges are created dynamically when someone dials in, and destroyed automatically when the last member leaves the bridge.

Using the [node-ari-client](https://github.com/asterisk/node-ari-client) library from the Asterisk project, and following some of their example code, this is what I have so far.

```js
var client = require("ari-client");
var util = require("util");

client.connect("http://localhost:8088", "username", "password")

.then(function (ari) {

    ari.once("StatisStart", channelJoined);

    function channelJoined (event, incoming) {

        incoming.on("BridgeCreated", function(event, bridge) {
            console.log(util.format("Bridge created: %s", bridge.id));
        });

        incoming.on("BridgeDestroyed", function(event, bridge) {
            console.log(util.format("Bridge destroyed: %s", bridge.id));
        });

        incoming.on("ChannelEnteredBridge", function(event, channel) {
            console.log(util.format("Bridge was joined by: %s", channel.id));
        });

        incoming.on("ChannelLeftBridge", function(event, channel) {
            console.log(util.format("Bridge was joined by: %s", channel.id));
        });
    }

    ari.start("bridge-watcher");
})

.done();
```

I expected that the `.on()` handlers would print to the console when the various events occurred. However, calling into a bridge, leaving a bridge, nothing is ever printed to console.

If it matters, here's the output of `npm ls` showing which versions I'm using. Node is v0.10.36.

```
├─┬ ari-client@0.5.0
│ ├── backoff-func@0.1.2
│ ├── bluebird@2.9.34
│ ├── node-uuid@1.4.1
│ ├─┬ swagger-client@2.0.26
│ │ ├── btoa@1.1.1
│ │ └─┬ shred@0.8.10
│ │   ├── ax@0.1.8
│ │   ├── cookiejar@1.3.1
│ │   ├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
│ │   └── sprintf@0.1.1
│ ├── underscore@1.6.0
│ └─┬ ws@0.4.31
│   ├── commander@0.6.1
│   ├── nan@0.3.2
│   ├── options@0.0.5
│   └── tinycolor@0.0.1
├── bluebird@3.1.1
└─┬ util@0.10.3
  └── inherits@2.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically, I want to know when a bridge has been created or
>   destroyed, and when a user (channel) has joined or left the bridge. On
>   my server, bridges are created dynamically when someone dials in, and
>   destroyed automatically when the last member leaves the bridge.

Remember: the *primary* purpose of ARI is to [build your own dialplan applications](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29395573#AsteriskRESTInterface%28ARI%29-ARI:AnInterfaceforCommunicationsApplications), not to monitor the entirety of Asterisk. As such, by default, your external application is not subscribed to the resources in Asterisk. As the [Channels in a Stasis Application](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Introduction+to+ARI+and+Channels#IntroductiontoARIandChannels-ChannelsinaStasisApplication) section explains:

> Resources in Asterisk do not, by default, send events about themselves to a connected ARI application. In order to get events about resources, one of three things must occur:
>
> 1. The resource must be a channel that entered into a Stasis dialplan application. A subscription is implicitly created in this case. The subscription is implicitly destroyed when the channel leaves the Stasis dialplan application.
> 2. While a channel is in a Stasis dialplan application, the channel may interact with other resources - such as a bridge. While channels interact with the resource, a subscription is made to that resource. When no more channels in a Stasis dialplan application are interacting with the resource, the implicit subscription is destroyed.
> 3. At any time, an ARI application may make a subscription to a resource in Asterisk through application operations. While that resource exists, the ARI application owns the subscription.

If you're expecting to get events automatically for resources in Asterisk that channels are using outside of the `bridge-watcher` application, you won't get them unless you do one of two things:

1. Explicitly subscribe to the resources using the [applications resource](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Applications+REST+API#Asterisk13ApplicationsRESTAPI-subscribe). This works well for resources that are relatively static and/or long lived, such as Endpoints, static Bridges (such as those used for Conferences), Mailboxes, and Device States. It does not work well for transitory resources.
2. In Asterisk 13.6.0 and later, you can now subscribe to all event sources when you connect your WebSocket. In `node-ari-client`, you would do the following:

   ari.start(bridge-watcher, true);

You should note however that even when you are subscribed to all resources, you don't explicitly *own* them. You merely can watch them all automatically. The notion of ownership is very important in ARI, particularly as it pertains to what you can and cannot do to channels, and when. The wiki pages I've linked provide some reasonable documentation for how this works.

Comment: Another member of my team suggests that I should be looking to AMI instead. Would that be a better route than continuing to try using ARI?